# Double (unneeded) notification about an answer or comment when following a comment\answer mail notification

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

When I follow an email link from a Stack Exchange site:

> new item in your Stack Exchange inbox

the link leads me straight to the comment/answer with a url ending with something like:

`?noredirect=1#comment1111111_2222222` (some comment number)

But the notification sign in the Stack Exchange inbox (uppper right side) shows me I've got a new item. When I go there I usually find it's exactly the item I just saw.

I believe the correct behavior to be that the notification should appear only for answers/comments I didn't see yet. Especially if I followed a link to that exact answer/comment.

I noticed this behavior at least in 3 Stack Exchange sites: Stack Overflow, Wordpress, Apps

Comment: Disabling email notifications would be a good idea if you are a regular visitor anyway.  But I agree that the logic isn't sophisticated enough.

Comment: Maybe edit the title of this post, though?  It sounds like a bug report about genuine duplicates.